# file stream exception on reading zip file (how to use using block)

Tags: c#, sharpcompress

I'm using the SharpCompress library (that's not the problem). My zips are either unprotected or are password protected (all with the same password). so I'm coding it like this:

```
using(Stream stream = File.OpenRead(file))
{
    try {
        reader = ZipReader.Open(stream);
        moreFiles = reader.MoveToNextEntry();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        reader = ZipReader.Open(stream, pwd);
        moreFiles = reader.MoveToNextEntry();
    }
    //rest of code
}
```

It always raises an obscure 'invalid header: xxxxxxxx' exception whenever it gets to the catch block to call `MoveToNextEntry` because I think the stream is not at the start.

I cannot put a `File.OpenRead(file)` inside the exception because I'm using a `using` block. If I use (as suggested in comments) a seek, I get an object reference not set (presumably dispose has been called).

Is there a way to reset this file stream and still ensure it gets disposed (while still using the `using` block). I didn't know if calling open again would cause the `using` block to be a bit unhappy also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following:

```
try
{
    reader = ZipReader.Open(stream);
    moreFiles = reader.MoveToNextEntry();
}
catch (CryptographicException e) when (e.Message == "No password supplied for encrypted zip.")
{
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    reader = ZipReader.Open(stream, pwd);
    moreFiles = reader.MoveToNextEntry();
}
```

Comment: I get an exception of object reference not set. Presumably the dispose has been called then?

Comment: I've just tried it with SharpCompress 0.11.5 and it worked. I'm updating the answer with the full code I've tried. I've also edited the catch statement to just handle the exception for password protection. If you're not in C# 6.0 you can omit the when directive.

Comment: Thanks :) I guess I missed out the open afterwards.